# Finding all spanning trees of a strongly connected directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have a strongly connected directed graph with about 10 vertices and 20 edges, and would like to find all spanning trees anchored at each vertex. Is there a systematic way, or a tested program/algorithm that would help me find all these spanning trees?

When I was looking at graphs with a smaller number of vertices and edges, I could simply write the spanning trees at each vertex out, but this gets more cumbersome when the graph gets bigger. Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by "anchored at each vertex"? Any spanning tree will use each vertex.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [paper](http://research.nii.ac.jp/~uno/papers/isaac96web.pdf) by Takeaki Uno, An algorithm for enumerating all directed spanning trees in a directed graph, should help you solve your problem.